# My callback_url endpoint in WooCommerce Rest API won't Fire

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on a php application that requires me to interact with each merchants store using the WooCommerce Rest API and i am trying to auto-generate the rest api keys like it was documented on their documentation but my callback_url endpoint won't fire and i don't receive the auto-generated keys sent to the callback endpoint.

Here is my code to Create an authentication endpoint URL

```
 public function integrate()
    {
            $url = $this->input->post('url');
            $title = $this->input->post('title');


            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('client_id');

            $save = $this->Store_model->save_store($user_id,$url, $title);

            $genKeyEndpoint = '/wc-auth/v1/authorize';
            $params = [
                'app_name' => 'App Name',
                'scope' => 'read_write',
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'return_url' => base_url('stores/integrateForm'),
                'callback_url' => base_url('stores/callback-endpoint')
            ];


            $query_string = http_build_query( $params, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 );



            $wooAuth = $url . $genKeyEndpoint . '?' . $query_string;

            redirect($wooAuth);
    }
```

and here is my code to retrieve the generated keys and store in my database

```
 public function save_api_key() {


        $post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        $wooResponseData = [
              'consumer_key'    => $post_data['consumer_key'],
              'consumer_secret' => $post_data['consumer_secret']
            ];

        $this->Store_model->updateStoreKeys($this->session->userdata('client_id'), $wooResponseData);

    }
```

My application is running on codeigniter.

Comment: Did you find the cause?